# Como usar uma variavel no atributo text do metodo button no tkinter PYTHON

Tags: python, variáveis, tkinter, button

Queria saber se tem como eu colocar uma variável no atributo text do método button da biblioteca do python
Por exemplo

```
nome = matheus
window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x500")
botao = Button(window, text="nome", command = none).grid(column=0, row=0)
```

entende oque eu queria fazer? eu gostaria de invés do texto do botão ser "nome", eu queria que aparecesse o conteúdo da variável

Answer (score -2):

30 segundos depois de postar a pergunta achei a solução
e agora to me achando um idiota
caso alguem um dia tenha a mesma duvida a solução é simples
tire as aspas e coloque o nome da variavel
Exemplo:

```
nome = matheus
window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x500")
botao = Button(window, text=nome, command = none).grid(column=0, row=0)
```